# How to correctly apply "in which", "of which", "at which", "to which", etc?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

How does one correctly apply “in which”, “of which”, “at which”, “to which”, etc.?

I'm confused with which one to apply when constructing sentences around these.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you be more specific and perhaps give some examples of sentences that you're not sure about?

Comment: I actually think there is a general idea expressed in English when a which + a preposition is used in English...

Comment: @J.He, Also see http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/where-versus-in-which

Comment: And http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv286.shtml

Comment: This question does not appear to be about the English language?? That's a laugh and a half.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The trick to knowing how to use; *of which*, *at which*, *in which*, *to which*, *from which* is to analyse the prepositional phrases, phrasal verbs, verbs and prepositions:

> 1. He /spoke of/ war and peace and many other topics that day.
>      The topic /**of which** he spoke/ was complex.
>      The verb here that means to speak about a topic is /to speak/ *of* a topic/: to mention
> 2. The party /**at which**/ he spoke/ was noisy.
>      Phrase: A party is held /*at* a place/. It is implied.
> 3. The situation /**in which**/ we found ourselves was dire.
>      Phrase: /to find oneself /*in* a situation.
> 4. The bonds /**from which**/ we broke free were tight.
>      phrase: to /break free/ *from* bonds.
> 5. The town /**to which**/we were driving was 50 ks away.
>      phrase: to /drive/ *to* a place.

Summary (and not a complete answer but a general one): The preposition depends on the verb that takes a preposition, a phrasal verb that includes a preposition, or it depends on the prepositional phrase used. Also, there are many other prepositions that can be paired with which: under, during, about, over, etc.

Comment: What's the difference between "The topic he spoke were complex." vs "*The topic /of which he spoke/ were complex*"?

Comment: And also "The town which we were driving to was 50 ks away" vs "*The town /to which/we were driving was 50 ks away*".

Comment: @Pacerier /The topic he spoke/ is not grammatical/idiomatic. To speak ON or OF or ABOUT a topic. All with different meanings. In the second sentence the only difference is informality/spoken English versus more formal/written English

Comment: Do `The party at which he spoke was noisy.` and `The party which he spoke at was noisy.` have different meanings?

Comment: @Lambie What about *Which*? without *in* at first.

Comment: @Mr. Hyde One can sometimes shift the  preposition in writing or in speech, yes: "the party which he spoke at was" etc.. Bear in mind, though, that in non-literary writing, the preposition would not be shifted. Which without in is not part of this question. The point here is about the prepositioins.

Comment: let add this to here too, someone check if is RIGHT or WRONG: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/when-to-use-which-or-in-which-or-that-as-relative-pronouns

Comment: @deadManN Yes, that's fine and it is a completely different question, in fact. My answer is about **which preposition to use**, not where to place it....

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to explain through examples. Each phrase simply means "the thing that we've already mentioned", e.g.

- The box in which the books are kept
- The town of which we were speaking
- The time at which we will arrive
- The destination to which we were heading

I'm sure there's a grammatically-correct term, but they're really just the correct forms of "the box the books are kept in"/"the town we were speaking of", i.e. removing the trailing preposition.

Comment: I've seen them called a 'complex relative phrase', in contrast to a 'simple relative phrase' which consists of a relative word on its own (e.g. "which", "who", "why" etc.)

Comment: The point is to know which preposition to use: in, of, about, in, under, over, etc.  You are not answering the question. speak of a matter, of which; fall under a statute, under which, arrive at a time, at which. And so forth.