# Use of "of which"?

Tags: meaning

Is this correct? or can the same thing be written in a better/more correct way?:

"The country has 2 million inhabitants, of which 300000 reside in the capital."
Thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me.  It means the same thing as "300000 of the country's 2 million inhabitants reside in the capital."  See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322836

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Certainly it could be written differently; whether or not the alternatives would be considered "better" is up for debate.

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [ES](https://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer to use *of whom* here, since inhabitants are people. But *of which* isn't incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with it at all. It's equivalent to saying:

"The country has 2 million inhabitants."

"300,000 of the country's 2 million inhabitants reside in the capital."