# What is the difference between "in which" and plain "which"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

What is the difference between "in which" and plain "which"? Can they be used interchangeably?
For instance what is the difference between these two sentences:

```
The party in which I attended was fun.
```

vs

```
The party which I attended was fun.
```

Comment: Do you have examples? As your question stands, it’s not clear where your confusion may lie.

Comment: The use of "in" is because there is a preposition phrase that requires it.  Not because it is tied to *which* in some way.

Comment: Try this as an example "Go down the corridor and find the door _which_ has my name on it. In that room is my desk _on which_ is a folder, _in which_ is the agenda for this meeting." Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic example of *in which* not being replaceable with *which* may be seen in the film [**In Which We Serve**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Which_We_Serve).

Of course, to be strictly correct, it is the *title* of the film in which the example can be seen, not *the film itself.*

More broadly, if Thing 1 can be *verb* + *in* Thing 2, then Thing 2 is the thing *in which* Thing 1 is *verbed*.

> Paddington Bear got lost in the Early Stamp Section of the Royal Postal Museum.  The Early Stamp Section was subsequently much remarked upon for being the section of the museum in which Paddington Bear got lost.

There are many ways to phrase a thought. However, *in which* and similar expressions make it possible for the writer to put their main idea at the place in the sentence that gives it the greatest impact - the point *at which* the speaker’s emphasis most naturally falls.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer, I don't feel like they can be used completely interchangeably, but there may be sentences where they can be swapped with little to no semantic change and still remain grammatically correct.

> M. C. asked a question in which the difference between 'in which' and plain 'which' was raised.

vs.

> M. C. asked a question which raised the difference between 'in which' and plain 'which'.

Both of these sentences are valid and mean the same thing.  But the sentence had to adjust to accommodate dropping the 'in'.  If I knew your pronouns, the first version could be modified to a more active tense for the prepositional phrase which would require a more substantial change to drop the 'in'.

I do feel more examples could help qualify exactly how to describe the difference.

See also [How to correctly apply "in which", "of which", "at which", "to which", etc?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322836/how-to-correctly-apply-in-which-of-which-at-which-to-which-etc/322866), in which the matter is further discussed, though I don't feel it makes this a duplicate because that was closed as being off topic, possibly for being too broad.

Comment: Both of those examples, but especially the first one, seem awkward to me. The phrasing I would use is "...a question about the difference between...".

Comment: This is really an awesome and thorough answer. I was going to pipe in, but you really said it right to the point. Thanks!

Comment: @Laurel I think the word 'contrived' fits a bit more than awkward.  At least, to me, contrived has awkward implicit within it, but also explains a bit why it's awkward.  I would have also used that same phrasing, but for the fact that I was going for an example in which either 'in which' or 'which' could be applied... and there I might have my example of a case where 'in which' works but 'which' doesn't without a whole bunch of rewording.